# Debug my asp.net mvc inside VS 2012 will return this error "HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, iis-express, windows-server-2012-r2

I am working on an asp.net mvc-4 web application inside visual studio 2012 professional. last week everything was working fine, where i were able to debug the project. but today when i debug my project i got this error:-

> HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error An error message detailing
>   the cause of this specific request failure can be found in the
>   application event log of the web server. Please review this log entry
>   to discover what caused this error to occur.

Here is the full details of the error:-
[image]

Now nothing has changed inside the code, but 2 days ago we got those windows updates installed:-
[image]

so can anyone advice what can be the issue?

Thanks

here is the full details of the error inside the IIS express

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type='text/xsl' href='freb.xsl'?>
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
<failedRequest url="http://localhost:65389/favicon.ico"
               siteId="2"
               appPoolId="Clr4IntegratedAppPool"
               processId="7644"
               verb="GET"
               authenticationType="NOT_AVAILABLE"               activityId="{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}"
               failureReason="STATUS_CODE"
               statusCode="500"
               triggerStatusCode="500"
               timeTaken="31"
               xmlns:freb="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2006/06/iis/freb"
               >
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-09-17T16:04:04.760Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="7644" ThreadID="6868"/>
  <Computer>****</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">FailedRequestsTracingModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotificationEvent">false</Data>
  <Data Name="NotificationStatus">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_END</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="NotificationStatus">NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-09-17T16:04:04.760Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="7644" ThreadID="6868"/>
  <Computer>****</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">RewriteModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotification">false</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-09-17T16:04:04.760Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="7644" ThreadID="6868"/>
  <Computer>****</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">RewriteModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotificationEvent">false</Data>
  <Data Name="NotificationStatus">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_END</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="NotificationStatus">NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-09-17T16:04:04.760Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="7644" ThreadID="6868"/>
  <Computer>*******8</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">ApplicationInitializationModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotification">false</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-09-17T16:04:04.760Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="7644" ThreadID="6868"/>
  <Computer>*******8</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">ApplicationInitializationModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotificationEvent">false</Data>
  <Data Name="NotificationStatus">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_END</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="NotificationStatus">NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-09-17T16:04:04.760Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="7644" ThreadID="6868"/>
  <Computer>*******8</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">WebSocketModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotification">false</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-09-17T16:04:04.760Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="7644" ThreadID="6868"/>
  <Computer>*******8</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">WebSocketModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotificationEvent">false</Data>
  <Data Name="NotificationStatus">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_END</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="NotificationStatus">NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-09-17T16:04:04.760Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="7644" ThreadID="6868"/>
  <Computer>*******8</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">ConfigurationValidationModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotification">false</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-09-17T16:04:04.760Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="7644" ThreadID="6868"/>
  <Computer>*******8</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">ConfigurationValidationModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotificationEvent">false</Data>
  <Data Name="NotificationStatus">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_END</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="NotificationStatus">NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-09-17T16:04:04.760Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="7644" ThreadID="6868"/>
  <Computer>*******8</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">AspNetInitClrHostFailureModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotification">false</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>3</Level>
  <Opcode>18</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-09-17T16:04:04.760Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="7644" ThreadID="6868"/>
  <Computer>*******8</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}</Data>
  <Data Name="ErrorDescription">An error message detailing the cause of this specific request failure can be found in the application event log of the web server.  Please review this log entry to discover what caused this error to occur.
</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_DESCRIPTION</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>3</Level>
  <Opcode>16</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-09-17T16:04:04.760Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="7644" ThreadID="6868"/>
  <Computer>*******8</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">AspNetInitClrHostFailureModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpStatus">500</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpReason">Internal Server Error</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpSubStatus">0</Data>
  <Data Name="ErrorCode">2147500035</Data>
  <Data Name="ConfigExceptionInfo"></Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="ErrorCode">Invalid pointer
 (0x80004003)</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-09-17T16:04:04.760Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="7644" ThreadID="6868"/>
  <Computer>*******8</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">AspNetInitClrHostFailureModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotificationEvent">false</Data>
  <Data Name="NotificationStatus">2</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_END</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">BEGIN_REQUEST</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="NotificationStatus">NOTIFICATION_FINISH_REQUEST</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-09-17T16:04:04.760Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="7644" ThreadID="6868"/>
  <Computer>*******8</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">CustomLoggingModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1024</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotification">false</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">LOG_REQUEST</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-09-17T16:04:04.760Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="7644" ThreadID="6868"/>
  <Computer>*******8</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">CustomLoggingModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">1024</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotificationEvent">false</Data>
  <Data Name="NotificationStatus">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_END</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">LOG_REQUEST</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="NotificationStatus">NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-09-17T16:04:04.760Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="7644" ThreadID="6868"/>
  <Computer>*******8</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">DynamicIpRestrictionModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">2048</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotification">false</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">END_REQUEST</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-09-17T16:04:04.760Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="7644" ThreadID="6868"/>
  <Computer>*******8</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">DynamicIpRestrictionModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">2048</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotificationEvent">false</Data>
  <Data Name="NotificationStatus">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_END</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">END_REQUEST</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="NotificationStatus">NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>1</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2019-09-17T16:04:04.760Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="7644" ThreadID="6868"/>
  <Computer>*******8</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-0300-0080010000F5}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">WebSocketModule</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">2048</Data>
  <Data Name="fIsPostNotification">true</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-GB">
  <Opcode>NOTIFY_MODULE_START</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">END_REQUEST</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>2</Opcode>
```

Comment: Can you check your web.config file and httpHandlers.Or, have to check if there was any update that would effect your setup, by going through KB

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling/repairing Visual Studio?

Comment: @JuhaKangas so you think the issue is with Visual Studio rather than been an issue with the windows server 20102 R2? as this visual studio was working well for me since 4++ years.. but not sure what happened suddenly ,, the only change is that we had some windows updates installed, as explained above.....

Comment: Something with you installation might have gotten messed up with the updates, I think the main thing is to get IIS Express reinstalled/repaired (which is what it runs on when you Debug) and a Visual Studio reinstall would include that.

You should also check the permissions for your physical path like the error says, seem odd those would change from an update but worth looking into.

Comment: @JuhaKangas thanks for the info , but can you advice more on which physical path i need to check? as i am an admin on the server...

Comment: I thought this was on your local environment and not on the server? Anyway, in the screenshot you posted above you censored the Physical Path value, try checking that folder for permissions.

Comment: Can you add output log from visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

0x80004003 error means E_POINTER. It sounds like some file or configuration was corrupted. Could you check system application event viewer? So we got to know what error message was logged when IIS express return 500.0 error.  Did you get the same error when you create a new application and debug it?

At the same time, you could try to enable failed request tracing. FRT log will tell us more information about this error.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Since the root cause of 500.0 could be complicated. You could try to rollback these update one by one. Then we may probably know find the KB that corrupted your IIS express.

If the steps are all not working, maybe you could try to reinstall IIS express.

In addition, I would recommend you MS process monitor:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon
It will tell us what files were read before IIS start logging error event. Then you could check whether these files has been corrupted.

Comment: I think the error is not directly related to IIS, as if i deploy the asp.net application inside the server's IIS it will work well, but the error i will get is when i run the project inside Visual Studio....

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend you to enable detailed error info in web.config.

```
<configuration>
 <system.web>
       <customErrors mode="Off" />
 </system.web>
</configuration>
```

After this you will be able to see real reason of an issue and fix it.

P.S. Most likely this is NOT related to windows update.

Comment: i already provided the full details of the error, check the screen which i provided... and custom errors are already disabled when debugging..